# oepnstack fuel - How can I remove fuel-master

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openstack

I installed FUEL in ubuntu 14.04. 
Now I have to remove all and re-install, But I don't know how to un-install FUEL
uname

```
Linux 3.13.0-129-generic #178-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 12:48:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Id    Name                           State
---------------------------------------------------
3     fuel_master                    running
```

Could you please give to way how to remove FUEL in ubuntu?